# HTTP POST check prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have set up the blackbox-exporter so that I can do a HTTP check on some of our API's. This is working great and is reporting correctly. However I also need to set up a HTTP POST check that doesn't seem to be working as well. I have included both http_2xx and http_post_2xx in the blackbox.yml and have then set up a new job_name for the HTTP POST checks (as i'm assuming i can't include it in the job with the normal HTTP checks?)

This is what my blackbox_exporter.yml looks like:

```
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 1m
    http:
      valid_status_codes: []
      method: GET
  http_post_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 1m
    http:
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/xml
      body: '{}'
```

And this is what Prometheus.yml looks like:

```
    - job_name: 'HTTP/API checks'
        scrape_interval: 1m
        metrics_path: /probe
        params:
          module: [http_2xx]
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/map/images/arrow-prev.png
            - http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/static//i/logo/ito_blue_white.png
            - http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp/text?but=login&size=9&border=5
            - http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/webapi/trip?guid=c56333323-f1c0-43ac-b2aa-cbaa1fdbc1d0&debug=true
           relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [__address__]
            target_label: __param_target
          - source_labels: [__param_target]
            target_label: instance
          - target_label: __address__
            replacement: xxxx.xxxxxxxx.com:9115

  - job_name: 'HTTP/API POST checks'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_post_2xx]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: xxxx.xxxxxxxx.com:9115
```

I'm just getting a down status from the check, however it is definitely up as we are currently using the same check in Nagios.

Really, I'd just like to know if there is any immediate flaws in the configs above or should this be working?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some more details on where you "get a down status"? Which metric are you looking at? `up` means up for the exporter process, not the target itself. But as you wrote the `GET` works, this should not be the case. Are you sure that the content-type `xml` is correct if you send a `json` payload?

Comment: Old question i know but adding: preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4" fixed this issue for me.